# Annotation specs - AutoML (VertexAi)

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

We're trying to build an imaged based product search for our webshop using the vertex ai image classification model (single label).

Currently we have around 20k products with xx images per product.
So our dataset containing 20k of labels (one for each product - product number), but on import we receive the following error message:

`There are too many AnnotationSpecs in the dataset. Up to 5000 AnnotationSpecs are allowed in one Dataset. Check your csv/jsonl format with our public documentation.`

Looks like not more than 5000 labels are allowed per Dataset... This quota is not really visible in the documentation - or we didn't find it.

Anyway, any ideas how we can make it work? Does we have to build 5 Datasets with 5 different Endpoints and than query every Enpoint for matching?

Answer (score 0):

You can find those limits in the [AutoML quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/quotas#limits) documentation.

It is possible to have multiple models for group of products -- Maybe even something like: one initial model to classify the product category (jewery, watches, shoes, toys, etc) and a second step for a specific model (to identify the specific product belong toys, or belong shoes, etc). But to be honest, it seems a bit hard to support - but certainly worth trying.

A second option would be [training a custom model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/custom-training) where you could do a fine tuning on some larger model (ie. inception, resnet, etc) do know all your 20k+ classes (products). It could add a little bit more work at first, but after established, it will become a single model for inference and re-training would be simpler using MLOps mechanisms (ie. Vertex Pipelines).